# How to delete multiple tables in one query?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

i need to delete two tables using same id. So far I was using this method:

```
public Integer deleteSplitMondayByID (String ID){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return database.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[]{ID});
    }
```

How I can add there one more table? I already tried something like

```
(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_NAME2 "ID = ?", new String[]{ID})
(TABLE_NAME + " , " + TABLE_NAME2 "ID = ?", new String[]{ID})
(TABLE_NAME + " UNION " + TABLE_NAME2 "ID = ?", new String[]{ID})
```

But I can't delete them. So, how I can make it?

Comment: This is not possible. Why do you want that?

Comment: You need to execute a single command for each table

Comment: By the way, the term "query", is referred only to a SELECT  statement. Of whichever complexity

Comment: Just run both delete statements in a single transaction so it'll appear atomic to anything else using the same database.

Answer (score 1):

As commented -- you can't delete from two table in a single statement, especially when it is abstracted in Java library. Try something like this:

```
public Integer deleteSplitMondayByID (String ID){
  int delcount = 0;
  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
  database.beginTransaction();
  try 
    {
      delcount += database.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[]{ID});
      delcount += database.delete(TABLE_NAME2, "ID = ?", new String[]{ID});
      database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {         
      database.endTransaction();
    }
  return delcount;
}
```